# how to print html particular size

Tags: html, printing

I created an html that I need will be printable. It looks ok online, however when I send it to the printer it looks huge. How can I adjust the size so it will be printed as A6 or A4 size?

Comment: i believe this is controlled through the computer's printing module

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define a different stylesheet for printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

[Print stylesheet - the definitive guide](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)